# WPF application. How to reference image in xaml code, so another user can view them when running .exe file of the project?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I'm having a problem with my wpf application. I have two images in the xaml code, and when I run the application on my computer, they appear well, but when I ask someone to run the .exe file, the application run but the images don't appear. How can I set the images source so that when another user run the .exe file, the images appear in the screen?

The xaml image source code:

```
Source="\\MULINFSV0005\User$\mathias.deitos\Meus Documentos\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\clock.png"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an image is in the project folder so probably the problem is in it's Properties.

Build Action: Resource

Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy

In xaml something like this  `<Image Source="../../Images/yorImage.png"/>` The path to the image from the place where you're (mean from the current file to the image file. If both files are in the same directory `Source="image.png"`

This should work.

Comment: Check the xaml peace, added to the reply. In fact yours is wrong, if you write Source="clock.png" it should be enough

Comment: Thanks a lot Anastasia Melnikova! Now it worked. As you said, i just deleted all the path to the image in the xaml code, and just let the image name:

Source="\MULINFSV0005\User$\mathias.deitos\Meus Documentos\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\clock.png"

Deleted all the path:

Source="clock.png"

Thanks again!